# sumSeriesWithWildcard confusion

Tags: graphite, grafana

Given a query in grafana

```
stats.counters.prod.something1.something2.*.cars.*.*.count
```

and I want to create a graph that will show me the sum of the counters split by the first `*`:
so if the first * are a,b,c,d I would get 4 lines in the graph which will show me the counts of a,b,c and d where the rest of metrics will be summed

I would add `sumSeriesWithWildcards(4)`. But if I add a sumSeriesWithWildcards(6) and sumSeriesWithWildcards(7) it changes the results, and also the order between then changes

How can I know which order of sumSeriesWithWildcards I should choose to get the correct result and what does `sumSeriesWithWildcards` mean really?

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you chose the `sumSeriesWithWildcards` that best capture the data you want to see in your graph. It depends on the structure of your metrics and what you want to summarize. In the example query `stats.counters.prod.something1.something2.*.cars.*.*.count`, if you want to see the sum of the counts of the different values of the first *, you should use `sumSeriesWithWildcards(4)`.

Answer (score -1):

The change in order and the change in results could be because `sumSeriesWithWildcards` basically calls `sumSeries` and interpolates the wildcard values into the query.

You can read the documentation of both `sumSeries` and `sumSeriesWithWildcards` [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.sumSeries)